# SVGnest mangles the SVG paths

Tags: svg

I created an SVG with Inkscape and Illustrator and want to optimize the layout with [SVGnest](http://www.svgnest.com).

But SVGnest mangles my paths completely. This screenshot shows the SVG in Illustrator to the right and in SVGnest to the left:

[image: SVGnest mangles the SVG paths]

SVGnest does this for about half my paths, which are all letters expanded from the fonts Arial MT Rounded, Chalkboard SE, and Cursivestandard. I chose the "g" letter above because it is striking. For the example above, use "g" in Chalkboard SE and expand its appearance, or copy-paste these lines into a file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 15.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="394.117px" height="136.135px" viewBox="0 0 394.117 136.135" enable-background="new 0 0 394.117 136.135"
     xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="#010101" d="M246.555,59.594c2.682-1.75,4.538-3.846,5.507-6.209c0.912-2.167,1.375-4.774,1.375-7.75V14.236
    c0-0.238-0.034-0.476-0.102-0.704c-0.382-1.3-1.036-2.346-1.947-3.108c-0.854-0.755-1.869-1.211-2.942-1.323
    c-1.156-0.165-2.265,0.074-3.276,0.698c-0.189,0.107-0.37,0.226-0.542,0.355c-0.788-0.449-1.604-0.878-2.448-1.285
    c-2.197-1.01-4.496-1.431-6.837-1.253c-2.253,0.173-4.393,0.79-6.306,1.804c-1.944,0.971-3.706,2.327-5.236,4.027
    c-1.523,1.691-2.699,3.586-3.503,5.653c-0.938,2.482-1.414,5.161-1.414,8.008c0.055,2.779,0.555,5.44,1.505,7.955
    c1.017,2.542,2.535,4.775,4.513,6.64c2.075,1.956,4.666,3.214,7.618,3.724c1.395,0.289,2.806,0.38,4.202,0.269
    c1.294-0.057,2.604-0.222,3.893-0.491c0.065-0.014,0.13-0.03,0.193-0.048c0.538-0.158,1.067-0.317,1.587-0.475v1.172
    c0,0.64-0.023,1.359-0.07,2.139c-0.025,0.435-0.109,0.778-0.279,1.069c-0.281,0.506-0.667,0.904-1.237,1.253
    c-0.599,0.388-1.26,0.665-2.047,0.852c-1.582,0.396-3.379,0.363-4.728,0.063c-0.58-0.134-1.093-0.267-1.467-0.378
    c-0.296-0.099-0.599-0.234-0.903-0.403c-0.064-0.036-0.131-0.069-0.199-0.1c-0.312-0.139-0.634-0.318-0.955-0.532
    c-0.056-0.037-0.113-0.072-0.171-0.104c-0.451-0.251-1.001-0.551-1.652-0.901c-0.138-0.074-0.282-0.136-0.432-0.183
    c-1.457-0.46-2.825-0.474-4.027-0.043c-0.048,0.017-0.097,0.036-0.144,0.057c-1.157,0.496-2.057,1.24-2.673,2.209
    c-0.029,0.047-0.058,0.094-0.084,0.143c-0.553,1.012-0.747,2.17-0.579,3.442c0.008,0.054,0.017,0.108,0.027,0.162
    c0.245,1.226,0.872,2.35,1.863,3.341c0.166,0.166,0.354,0.308,0.56,0.421c1.441,0.795,2.735,1.48,3.77,1.996
    c1.284,0.701,2.847,1.255,4.623,1.644c1.525,0.347,3.115,0.522,4.724,0.522c0.955,0,1.938-0.062,2.839-0.176
    c1.322-0.121,2.655-0.453,3.96-0.987C244.318,60.868,245.466,60.281,246.555,59.594z M242.394,21.9v10.685
    c-1.91,1.428-3.795,2.124-5.748,2.124c-1.32,0-2.709-0.33-4.134-0.981c-0.187-0.207-0.383-0.414-0.591-0.622
    c-0.156-0.157-0.305-0.313-0.445-0.47c-1.142-2.617-1.641-4.996-1.486-7.036c0.18-1.912,1.212-3.88,3.068-5.856l0.744-0.372
    c0.297-0.133,0.584-0.266,0.86-0.398l2.588-0.216c0.968,0.321,1.903,0.786,2.812,1.404C240.91,20.717,241.691,21.299,242.394,21.9z"
    />
</svg>
```

Does anyone know how to avoid this?

Note: I first asked the question in a comment in [this thread](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/111299/automatically-rotate-and-translate-paths-to-reduce-space-without-them-touching).

Answer (score 1):

Following [these comments](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/111299/automatically-rotate-and-translate-paths-to-reduce-space-without-them-touching#comment-166839), the problem is from using Safari, not from SVGnest. SVGnest does not mangle the paths in Firefox or Google Chrome.

See also this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Jack000/SVGnest/issues/71).