# Image fitting in minimal space

Tags: images, layout

Is there any way to orgazine certain images to fit in a document occupying the minimal space possible? Like this:

[image]

The images would be in a PNG format, to count transparent areas as free space to insert another image (any other image format that supported transparency would work as well).

I was looking for some script that did this on a program (such as Adobe Photoshop, Microsoft Word...) or even a program itself that would do it.

My purpose is to print some stickers and I wanted to fit as much as I could of them into a single page to save up paper (and work on fitting them by hand).

Comment: See https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/111299/automatically-rotate-and-translate-paths-to-reduce-space-without-them-touching

Comment: @Tetsujin That looks like a valid solution, although it only works with vector images for what I've seen

Comment: Perhaps you could import your images into vector software, mask with a vector shape then use the solution in the duplicate