# Fit all objects on a canvas for best plotter density in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I have 10-15 objects in my svg. Is there a way to make Inscape to lay those on a canvas in the best way for further plotting? So it would rotate and reposition all objects and they won't overlap and will have as small gaps as possible between all objects. At the same time fit the canvas.

Comment: There's nothing in Inkscape as far as I know. However, see this closely related question: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/111299/89608

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no tool or extension to do this automatically inside Inkscape.

However there is an online tool, [SVGnest](https://svgnest.com/) for this purpose. Also [Deepnest.io](https://deepnest.io/) which seems to be the standalone desktop version.